# Why is delete working in app but not in tests?

Tags: java, testing, spring-data-jpa, mockmvc

Here's my case.

> Category.java

```
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "masterCategory.id")
  private MasterCategory masterCategory;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Expense> expenses = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

> Expense.java

```
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Expense {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private String itemName;
  private LocalDateTime expenseDate;
  private String shopName;
  private boolean isIncome;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "shop.id")
  private Shop shop;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "bankingAccount.id")
  private BankingAccount bankingAccount;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="category.id")
  private Category category;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "userAccount.id")
  private UserAccount userAccount;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "userGroup.id")
  private UserGroup userGroup;

}
```

As we can see, they are linked though a relation.
I also have simple service, repository and controller (spring boot) for each of these class. CategoryService contains method for deleting controller. Its also quite simple.

```
Category category = categoryRepository.selectCategory(getLoggedUsername(),groupId,masterCatId,categoryId);
categoryRepository.delete(category);
return categoryConverter.toMinimalDto(category);
```

And when I run the app, everything works perfectly, its removing the category from database, its removing expenses connected to that category.
One day I decided to write tests cause I was tired of checking everything manually. Heres the test method:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = LOGIN)
public void shouldDeleteCategoryAndConnectedExpenses__andReturn200() throws Exception {
    //given
    mvc.perform(get("/api/budget/1/master/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json(testUtil.openJson("categories/categoriesFromSelectedBudget.json")));
    mvc.perform(get("/api/budget/1/master/1/category/1/expense"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json(testUtil.openJson("expenses/expensesFromCategory1.json")));
    //when
    mvc.perform(delete("/api/budget/1/master/1/category/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    //then
    mvc.perform(get("/api/budget/1/master/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json(testUtil.openJson("categories/categoriesAfterDelete.json")));
    mvc.perform(get("/api/budget/1/master/1/category/1/expense"))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

I have a special `postgresDB` for tests, here I check if delete is really doing its job. I do this by checking if response jsons are the ones I want them to be. Simple stuff.

- First `get` (categoriesFromSelectedBudget.json) contains 3 elements
- Third `get` (categoriesAfterDelete.json) contains 2 elements.

These jsons are 100% correct.

The question is: why when application is run, everything works correctly (I can see SQLs with delete, correct rows are deleted from DB) but when tests are run the follwoing exception is thrown:

> java.lang.AssertionError: []: Expected 2 values but got 3

In test, delete gives me http 200 but it's clearly not deleting the element. Also there are no SQLs with delete. Why? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post your jpa database configuration for both you tests and app, please? Since you are using different database, some settings might not be the same.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to see if the query is ran and what is the query. Try to run that query manually on the test database to see if it actually deletes the row.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for leads. After some debugging I realised that test behave like this because of `@Transactional` on top of the test class. I did it to refresh database after each method. I replaced it with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` and everything seems to work fine.